# how can i dynamically maintain bootstrap tabs id for each post loops

Tags: php, loops

The problem is For every iteration (loops) i cant maintain dynamically tabs id for every post. so how can i solve this.
Suppose on the basis of condition 10 post found and for every post when i click the tab menu it also opens others post tab.

```
<?php  
        $qu= "select * from comment";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qu);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){  
            while($row1 =mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">TAB2</li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">TAB3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
            echo "foo1";
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
            echo "foo2";
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
            echo "foo3";
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
            } 
        }
          else {
            echo 'No result Found';
        } 
    ?>
```

I hope the problem clearly i clearly described if not then please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create id for each post too, somethings like this:

```
<?php  
        $qu= "select * from comment";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qu);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){  
            $count = 1; // this line added
            while($row1 =mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                $post_id = 'post_'.$count.'_'; // this line added
    ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $post_id; ?>1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $post_id; //this line updated ?>2">TAB2</li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $post_id; //this line updated ?>3">TAB3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="<?php echo $post_id; //this line updated ?>1" class="tab-pane fade in active ">
            echo "foo1";
        </div>
        <div id="<?php echo $post_id; //this line updated ?>2" class="tab-pane fade">
            echo "foo2";
        </div>
        <div id="<?php echo $post_id; //this line updated ?>3" class="tab-pane fade">
            echo "foo3";
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
            $count++; //this line added
            } 
        }
          else {
            echo 'No result Found';
        } 
    ?>
```

in addition don't use  `mysqli_*` functions , They expired; [use PDO class](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)